# overflow in mpz type using gmp mpz_pow_ui

Tags: c++, overflow, gmp, exponentiation

I am getting an overflow error when calling `mpz_pow_ui` from `gmp`, with the maximum `unsigned long int` value.
According to the signature [here](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation), this is supposed to work, shouldn’t it?
What am I missing?

Example:

example.cpp:

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <limits>

int main(){
  unsigned long int exp = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long int>::max();
  mpz_t result;
  mpz_t three;
  mpz_init(three);
  mpz_set_ui(three, 3);
  mpz_pow_ui(result, three, exp);
}
```

```
$ gcc -oexample example.cpp -lgmp
$ ./example 
gmp: overflow in mpz type
Aborted
```

Comment: You are missing enough memory to store the result...

Comment: You didn't initialize `result`.

Answer (score 2):

Common beleif is that GMP is truly an arbitrary precision software, from the front [page](https://gmplib.org/):

> What is GMP?
> GMP is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on signed integers, rational numbers, and floating-point numbers. There is no practical limit to the precision except the ones implied by the available memory in the machine GMP runs on.

But that is (unfortunately) not true. A `grep` on the GMP code for the error `overflow in mpz type` shows it appears in `mpz/init2.c`, `mpz/realloc.c`, and `mpz/realloc2.c`. Basically (if you are not running on a CRAY machine), the abort you got happens here:

```
if (UNLIKELY (new_alloc > INT_MAX))
{
  fprintf (stderr, "gmp: overflow in mpz type\n");
  abort ();
}
```

Thus whenever you try to create or calculate a number with more than `2^31 - 1` *limbs* (or machine words), GMP will abort. This is because the limbs of a number are accessed by an `int` index:

```
typedef struct
{
  int _mp_alloc;        /* Number of *limbs* allocated and pointed to by the _mp_d field.  */
  int _mp_size;         /* abs(_mp_size) is the number of limbs the last field points to.  If _mp_size is negative this is a negative number.  */
  mp_limb_t *_mp_d;     /* Pointer to the limbs.  */
} __mpz_struct;
...
typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

So, there is a practical limit for what GMP can calculate (note that on most machines you will won't have that much RAM anyway, but there are special computers with very large RAM, and those require `long` indexing).

**EDIT:** INT_MAX is a definition from the standard (Appendix E - Implementation limits) defintion of numeric limits, `limits.h`, which was included in GMP in `gmp-impl.h` in [2014](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp-6.2/file/tip/ChangeLog#l3039):

```
#  define INT_MAX        2147483647
```

**EDIT 2:** The OP asks in a comment why is the parameter to `mpz_pow_ui` an `unsigned long int` and not an `unsigned int`, since it cannot compute with all of the values of an `unsigned long int` exponent. This is because GMP is, according to the [front page](https://gmplib.org/):

> What is GMP? GMP is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on signed integers, rational numbers, and floating-point numbers. There is no practical limit to the precision except the ones implied by the available memory in the machine GMP runs on. GMP has a rich set of functions, and the functions have a **regular interface**.

Well, all GMP functions named with an `ui` work with an `unsigned long int`, see [`mpz_get_ui`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Converting-Integers#index-mpz_005fget_005fui), [`mpz_add_ui`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Arithmetic#index-mpz_005fmul_005fui), [`mpq_set_ui`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Rationals#index-mpq_005fset_005fui), [`mpz_fac_ui`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Number-Theoretic-Functions#index-mpz_005ffib_005fui), [`mpf_add_ui`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Float-Arithmetic#index-mpf_005fadd_005fui), and many others.

Its just not worth to mix arbitrary precision `mpn_`, `mpz_`, and `mpq_` functions with simple `int`s or `unsigned int`s, since these are trivially converted to `long`s. That's one of the reasons they say the interface is *regular*, all functions named `ui` work with `unsigned long int`s and all functions named `si` work with `long int`s, no function that mixes native integer types with "arbitrary precision" integers work with simple non-long `int`s.

The `pow` functions are among the few of GMP's `ui` functions that cannot produce a result for a `long` argument, so it makes no sense to make only those functions to work with simple non-long `int`s, since this would confuse the interface.

But I agree that GMP maintainers should be more clear about the limitations of the library.

Comment: Hi @kelalaka, thanks for the feedback, but I don't think you should delete your answer, it took you time, and it has relevant information on it. Anyway, it's your choice. By the way, I'm new here, and I don't understand what you mean by "salvage my answer",  just specify what you want me to do and I'll do it, thanks.

Comment: it was my personal choice, nothing related to rules... Also, your answer needs the definition of the INT_MAX where the rabbit hole goes into [this](https://github.com/aixoss/gmp/blob/b2c5b997d4bf44e216f0bae6a85ca83e58a55564/gmp-h.in#L449)

Comment: Then, +1, for the companion answer. Enjoy.

Comment: Hi @kelalaka, sorry been away for a couple of days, I beleive INT_MAX comes from [standard](https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/limits.h.html) `limits.h` included in `gmp-impl.h`, see [here](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp-6.2/file/tip/gmp-impl.h#l50). The rabbit hole you mention is an old version (5.1.3) of GMP kept in AIXOSS, that definition of `__GMP_UINT_MAX` has been [removed](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp-6.2/file/tip/ChangeLog#l3039) in 2014 exactly because they included `limits.h`. Good thing you kept your answer, it adds to the knowledge base.

Answer (score 1):

There are various points to be considered in your code;

1. You have to init every variable. You can also use [Combined Initialization and Assignment Functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/Simultaneous-Integer-Init-_0026-Assign)

```cpp
 void mpz_init_set (mpz_t rop, const mpz_t op)
 void mpz_init_set_ui (mpz_t rop, unsigned long int op)
 void mpz_init_set_si (mpz_t rop, signed long int op)
 void mpz_init_set_d (mpz_t rop, double op)
```

2. You have to free the memory with `mpz_clear` or `mpz_clears`.
3. You use C++ to code, however, you are using C API of GNU/GMP. You may consider using the [C++ interface](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General).
4. The main function should `return`. If there is no `return` value, `0` is returned by default. Even in the void case, some programmers always prefer a return statement.
5. The exponent is too big; `3^18446744073709551615`. That is ~[10^18 digits](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E18446744073709551615)

```cpp
    #include <gmp.h>
    #include <limits>
    
    int main(){
    
     unsigned long int exp = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long int>::max();
    
      mpz_t result;
      mpz_t three;
      
      //init the memory
      mpz_init(three);
      mpz_init(result);
     
      mpz_set_ui(three, 3);
      mpz_pow_ui(result, three, exp);
    
      //free the memory
      mpz_clear(three);
      mpz_clear(result);

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Point 4 is wrong, `main` is a special case.

Comment: @MarcGlisse you are right, it was optional.

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks for the comments and for the fixed code. Notice that also with the fixed code, the error remains.

Comment: @YoniZohar You are trying to calculate an extremely long value `3^18446744073709551615`.  That is ~[10^18 digits](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E18446744073709551615). There is no way to store the result. Sorry for not testing the code for this part. Why do you need such an exponent? or Actually, do you need modular exponentiation?

Comment: This was a sanity check for me to understand the function. I was assuming that if the function takes an `unsigned long int` then it can handle any `unsigned long int`. If the true limit is smaller, as @Arc suggests, I wonder why doesn’t the function take an `unsigned int` instead.

Comment: Probably, because unsigned int can be represented in unsigned long int and to be compatible with the modular pair `powm`.